# Regex (Javascript) - How to replace certain character in a given string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following case:

"SUM(A, SUM(A1, B, C), SUM(D, A3, F, M))"

Is there I way I could identify all the cells/columns which are the following letters:

Cells: A1, B1, C1, ...
Columns: A, B, C, D, ...

COLUMNS are only A-Z

CELLS are [A-Z][1-*]

And replace only them & NOT replace any formula letter (i.e: SUM, AVERAGE, ...).

Comment: Can you describe a rule that distinguishes them? If you can, you can translate that to a regular expression.

Comment: E.g. Cells are a single letter followed by digits. Columns are a single letter. It should be trivial to translate both of those to regular expressions.

Comment: What happens if the sheet has more than 26 columns, though? Doesn't it start using multi-letter columns like `AA`, `AB`, etc.? That will probably make it impossible to do this with a regular expression.

Comment: @Mushroomator `*` should be `+`. Otherwise it will also match `1`.

Comment: And don't forget to anchor it to word boundaries with `\b` around it.

Comment: There is only A-Z OR [A-Z][1...*]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the goal is basically to avoid ending up replacing the formula letters.

Assuming you're able to use negative lookaheads, that could be done as simply as `\b[A-Z]+[0-9]*\b(?!\()`, since a formula will always be the letters followed by an open parenthesis.

Or, if you're positive there aren't more than 26 columns, then you could shorten it even more with `\b[A-Z][0-9]*\b(?!\()`. That is, removing the quantifier for the letter.

If there's some other constraint that would make this not work, then it would be helpful to have that information available in the question.

Comment: `0-9` should be `1-9`. There is no `0` column.

Comment: I think you mean row, right? However, if there is a row 10 or higher, then you would need a zero. I suppose you could be more precise with `[1-9]?[0-9]*` for that part.